# 長めの固有名詞が分割されてしまう

Tags: python, python3, mecab, 自然言語処理

分かち書きや形態素解析をする際、長めの固有名詞が2つに分割されてしまいます。
例）外国人　→　外国 / 人
これらをくっつけて出力する方法はありますでしょうか。
ユーザー辞書などに追加するしかないのでしょうか。
できればですが、基本的なMecabを使った以下のコードから改変したいです。

＊コード＊

```
import MeCab
m = MeCab.Tagger ("-Owakati")
print(m.parse ("外国人の生活費ランキング、トップは今年も香港　東京は２位"))
```

＊出力＊

```
外国 人 の 生活 費 ランキング 、 トップ は 今年 も 香港 　 東京 は ２ 位
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「何ををくっつけて何を分解するかという基準」を記述したものが辞書なので、そこに介入したいなら辞書をいじるしかないです。

「外国人」はipadicにもnaist-jdicにもjumandicにもないですね。
ipadic-neologd にはそのあたりの複合語のエントリが多く入っているので（実際「外国人」はあります）、ipadic-neologd を使うという手はありかと思います。
https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd

あと、本筋ではないですがまったく固有名詞ではありませんよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます！固有名詞じゃないですね...。お恥ずかしいです。